# Upgrade from xcode 4.5 to 4.5.1, error "Xcode cannot run using the selected device."

Tags: xcode

The project worked great in xcode 4.5, but broken just after upgrade to 4.5.1.

The error message when connect to device: "Xcode cannot run using the selected device."
"Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device."

I am very regret about the upgrade. And I've check the architecture and bundle names, but cannot fix the problem.

Is it possible to revert back to 4.5? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally resolved the problem by creating a new project, and add old files.

Answer (score 0):

Its just duplicated Info.plist file just use 1 Info.plist file in files then restart xcode its fixed for me